# spliting the string into desired format and creating an array out of it

Tags: javascript

I have a string which I want to break after every `</div>`  and insert into an array. Following is the string.

```
"<DIV title='Run of Network' id='525000000'>Run of Network</DIV>
<div title='3dServer11' id='525001499'>3dServer11</div>"
```

I thought of using `split()` function, but since this is not a comma separated string, I am not able to understand exactly how should I break the string and generate a array. In the array I want the single single div entries like:

```
a[0] = <DIV title='Run of Network' id='525000000'>Run of Network</DIV>
a[1] = <div title='3dServer11' id='525001499'>3dServer11</div>"
```

Can any one help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not render it in a container and parse tagname?

Comment: [Please, dont parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest you to split HTML strings with `split` method or to [parse it with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1249581). It is always better to operate elements with DOM methods:

```
var str = "<DIV title='Run of Network' id='525000000'>Run of Network</DIV>\
           <div title='3dServer11' id='525001499'>3dServer11</div>",
    div = document.createElement("div"),
    arr = [];

div.innerHTML = str;
arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(div.getElementsByTagName("div"));
arr = arr.map(function(e) { return e.outerHTML; });  // to create strings
                                                     // out of DOM elements
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: +1. Could add `arr.forEach(function(e,i,a) { a[i] = e.outerHTML; })`, so that `arr` stores strings and not element objects.

Comment: @Rikonator True, but maybe [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is better here. Anyway the OP needs to check browser compatibility to use these methods and add [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) if needed.

Comment: @ VisioN the above solution does not work with IE 8 it gives me   "Array.prototype.slice.call(div.getElementsByTagName("div")) JScript object expected Error"..how can I handle this. If it is not possible with the above solution can you provide another solution

Answer (score 3):

try

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = "<div title='Run of Network' id='525000000'>Run of Network</div><div title='3dServer11' id='525001499'>3dServer11</div>";
    $("#container").html(str);
    for (i = 0; i < $("#container").children().length; i++) {
        alert($("#container").children()[i].innerHTML);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:

Wrote a small jQuery plugin if you had a DOM element you wanted to do the same operation to:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.splitDOMStringsByTag = function( selector ) {
        var resultsArray = [];

        this.find( '> ' + selector).each(function() {
            resultsArray.push( $(this)[0].outerHTML.replace( /[\s\n\r]+/g, ' ' ) );
        });

        return resultsArray;
    };
})( jQuery );
```

**How this works:**

Suppose you had the following DOM

```
<ul id="abc">
    <li>One </li>
    <li>Two </li>
    <li>Three </li>
    <li>Three 
        <ul>
            <li>Three point five</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Four </li>
</ul>
```

You would then do the following:

```
var myArray = $('#abc').splitDOMStringsByTag('li');
```

And get the following Output

```
myArray; // console
["<li>One </li>", "<li>Two </li>", "<li>Three </li>", "<li>Three <ul> <li>Three point five</li> </ul> </li>", "<li>Four </li>"]

myArray[3] // console
"<li>Three <ul> <li>Three point five</li> </ul> </li>"
```

---

**Old Answer with plain JS**

```
var ipt = "<DIV title='Run of Network' id='525000000'>Run of Network</DIV><div title='3dServer11' id='525001499'>3dServer11</div>",
    dummyDiv = document.createElement("div"),
    divList = [],
    a = [];

dummyDiv.innerHTML = ipt;
divList = Array.prototype.slice.call(dummyDiv.getElementsByTagName("div"));

for (var i = 0; i < divList.length; i++) {
    a.push(divList[i]);
}
```

This would give you your desired `a` with

```
a[0] = <DIV title='Run of Network' id='525000000'>Run of Network</DIV>
a[1] = <div title='3dServer11' id='525001499'>3dServer11</div>
```

To get the strings, simply use `a[0].outerHTML`

```
a[0].outerHTML;

// Console Output
"<div title="Run of Network" id="525000000">Run of Network</div>"
```